# Транслитереция веб страницы с латиницы в кириллицу или наоборот

Tags: javascript, translit

Нужно сделать транслитерацию веб страницы из латиницы в кириллицу, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку сайт "перевелся" сразу же. Не знаю как быть и куда копать. Пробовал всю страницу взять в `<div id="translit"></div>` и перевести с помощью JS, тут он стал переводить и теги ...
У кого какие мысли ?

Comment: 1 - Зачем такая странная задача? 2 - Можно посмотреть Вашу имплементацию?

Comment: Ваш ответ зависит от этого ?

Comment: Конечно, нужно понять что конкретно Вы хотите реализовать и какие наработки уже есть.

Comment: использовал вот эту библиотеку http://masscode.ru/index.php/k2/item/28-litranslit. "Транслит НЕтекстового поля" но он переводит и HTML теги

Comment: Вам надо пройтись по *всем* тегам и в каждом выполнить функцию транслитерации.

Answer (score 1):

Очень простой вариант, но это должно помочь решить проблему.

```js
let alph = {' ':' ','а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e', 'ж': 'g', 'з': 'z','и': 'i', 'й': 'y', 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n', 'о': 'o', 'п': 'p','р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'u', 'ф': 'f', 'ы': 'i', 'э': 'e', 'А': 'A','Б': 'B', 'В': 'V', 'Г': 'G', 'Д': 'D', 'Е': 'E', 'Ж': 'G', 'З': 'Z', 'И': 'I','Й': 'Y', 'К': 'K', 'Л': 'L', 'М': 'M', 'Н': 'N', 'О': 'O', 'П': 'P', 'Р': 'R','С': 'S', 'Т': 'T', 'У': 'U', 'Ф': 'F', 'Ы': 'I', 'Э': 'E', 'ё': 'yo', 'х': 'h','ц': 'ts', 'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'shch', 'ъ': '', 'ь': '', 'ю': 'yu', 'я': 'ya','Ё': 'YO', 'Х': 'H', 'Ц': 'TS', 'Ч': 'CH', 'Ш': 'SH', 'Щ': 'SHCH', 'Ъ': '', 'Ь': '','Ю': 'YU', 'Я': 'YA'};

let translit = (str) => {
  return str.split("").map(item => {
    return alph[item];
  }).join("");
}

$("#btn").on("click", () => {
  $("#btn").off();
  $("body > #root *").each((index, elem) => {
    $(elem).contents().each((ite, item) => {
      if (item.nodeName === "#text") {
        item.textContent = translit(item.textContent);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <button id="btn">НАЖМИ ЧТОБЫ ПЕРЕВЕСТИ</button>
  <div>
    Привет, я текст на кириллице
    <span>Привет, я тоже</span>
    <button>Я тоже, если что</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    Привет, я текст на кириллице
    <span>Привет,<span>я вложенный спан</span></span>
    <ul>
      <li>А я элемент списка</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Misha Saidov, благодарю за подробный ответ. Но при нажатии на кнопку НАЖМИ ЧТОБЫ ПЕРЕВЕСТИ у меня почему то ничего не происходит. в консоли тоже нету ошибок...

Comment: @AlexStassov только что проверил в Chrome, Firefox и Edge - никаких ошибок все работает [https://i.imgur.com/kIx7VBx.gif](https://i.imgur.com/kIx7VBx.gif) (в ie суваться не стал)